# developing 2-d array in C with user input?

Tags: c

I'm doing some practicing with arrays and I'm a bit confused on the subject, it keeps printing out just one of the numbers entered but not a mix of different numbers from the user, what exactly am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main ()
{ 
    int a; 
    int b;
    int i; 
    int j; 

    printf(" Please enter a value for the first array"); 
    scanf(" %d", &a); 

    printf(" Please enter a value for the second array");  
    scanf(" %d", &b);

    double array[a][b]; 

    for( i = 0; i< a; i++) 
    { 

        for( j=0; j< b; j++)
        { 
            printf(" enter values or the arrays\n"); 
            scanf(" %lg", &array[a][b]); 
        } 

    }  

    for( i = 0; i< a; i++) 
    { 

        for( j=0; j< b; j++)
        { 
            printf("%lg", array[a][b]); 
        } 

       printf("\n"); 
    }   
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change to

`scanf(" %lg", &array[i][j]);`

instead

`scanf(" %lg", &array[a][b]);`

Also same for `pritntf`. It should

```
printf("%lg", array[i][j]);
```

Comment: I wonder why people see an answer an still wants to answer the **exactly the same**

Comment: @nightshade see answer posting time and check who posted early.

Comment: I know... that's why I didn't comment in the others... I know you did first, then someone else comes 5 minutes later and write the same thing.. @Jayesh

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
scanf(" %lg", &array[a][b]);
```

to

```
scanf(" %lg", &array[i][j]);
```

And change,

```
printf("%lg", array[a][b]);
```

to

```
printf("%lg", array[i][j]);
```

As `a` and `b` does not changed inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here a and b are the number of rows/columns in your 2d array.
`array[0][0]` means 1st row first column cell, `array[0][1]` means 1st row second column cell and so on, so `array[a][b]` means a+1th row b+1th column cell. In your loop, you keep changing values of i and j but a and b are always the same. Yet, every time you take in or printout `array[a][b]`. Thus you keep on overwriting and reading the same element over and over again. Instead use the variable you are changing in your loops, i.e., i and j

Instead of:

```
scanf(" %lg", &array[a][b]);
printf(" %lg", array[a][b]);
```

Use:

```
scanf(" %lg", &array[i][j]);
printf(" %lg", array[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array subscripts have a different meaning in a declaration than in other code. In a declaration, the integer within the brackets tells the compiler how much memory to allocate; in other code, it tells the compiler which element of the array to dereference.

Consequently, you need to use the running indices within the `scanf()` call, so replace

```
scanf(" %lg", &array[a][b]);
```

with

```
scanf(" %lg", &array[i][j]);
```

---

Note that code like

```
int foo[count];
foo[count] = 7;
```

is always an error because you are allocating space for `count` elements, which are accessed using indices from `0` to `count-1`. Accessing `foo[count]` manipulates memory just behind the allocation, possibly clobbering vital data at that location in memory. After such an error, anything may happen.

Answer (score 0):

It prints the same values because your for loops are wrong:

```
for( i = 0; i< a; i++) {
    for( j=0; j< b; j++){ 
         printf(" enter values or the arrays\n"); 
         scanf(" %lg", &array[a][b]);
    }
}
```

In every loop you save the values at the same array position. Just change the &Array[a][b] to &Array[i][j] as below:

```
for( i = 0; i< a; i++) { 
    for( j=0; j< b; j++) { 
        printf(" enter values or the arrays\n"); 
        scanf(" %lg", &array[i][j]); 
    } 
 }
```

Do the same for all for loops. Hope this helps you